# Need help about DOJO charts

Tags: charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I need same chart like mentioned in below URL from dojo library in my application.

http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGauges/demo.html

But unfortunately, I can't see HTML and JS code needed for above demo. Is there any way to find it somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for official documentation:
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/dgauges.html